# My Custom Route Handler Doesn't Work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am building an ASP.NET MVC 5 site, with some PDF files for registered members, only logged in users can download them through controller action; however, they are accessible by their physical URI as well. The url pattern is like:

localhost:00000/resfiles/filename.pdf

In order to restrict the access, I followed this [post](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/126/asp-net-mvc-prevent-image-leeching-with-a-custom-routehandler) to create a custom route handler, and I want to verify user's identity in the handler to prevent unauthorized downloading.

I have my RouteConfig.cs as:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.Add("PDFRoute", new Route("ResFiles/{filename}", new PDFRouteHandler()));

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ProductDetail",
            url: "NewProduct/Detail/{prdId}",
            defaults: new { controller = "NewProduct", action = "Detail", prdId = "" },
            namespaces: new[] { "Totara.Controllers" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { "Totara.Controllers" }
        );
    }
}
```

And defined a PDFRouteHandler class as:

```
namespace Totara.RouteHandlers
{
    public class PDFRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
    {
        public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            return new PDFHandler(requestContext);
        }
    }
}
```

And the PDFHandler:

```
namespace Totara.HttpHandlers
{
    public class PDFHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public PDFHandler(RequestContext context)
        {
            ProcessRequest(context);    // never reach here
        }

        private static void ProcessRequest(RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            var response = requestContext.HttpContext.Response; // never reach here
            var request = requestContext.HttpContext.Request;
            var server = requestContext.HttpContext.Server;
            var requestFile = requestContext.RouteData.Values["filename"].ToString();
            var path = server.MapPath("~/ResFiles/");
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            var test = "test";  // never reach here
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

    }

}
```

Go to the url in my browser: localhost:42439/ResFiles/BauerContractReview_Feb2015.pdf

The three breakpoints in PDFHandler.cs are never reached. What do I miss? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove ".pdf" form your URL your code will be executed. See also [this](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/3034/creating-a-custom-route-handler-in-aspnet-mvc) article. If you want to support ".pdf" then you have to configure IIS and register your handler in web.config. See [this](http://parassanghani.blogspot.nl/2011/02/creating-custom-http-handler.html) article for details.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried it. I go to: http://localhost:42439/ResFiles/BauerContractReview_Feb2015, and the breakpoints are not hit, and I get "The resource cannot be found." error returned.